# shared function in script and code block

Tags: powershell

I have a function that I use in my main script, and I also need to create a Job, which uses the same function. Right now I just have the code written twice, once in the main script, and once in the script block handed to the Job. I know I can add code to a variable, but not sure how to then unpack that variable in the code block, so the same code is effectively used in both places.
If it makes a difference, I am limited to v2 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a Module

Define your function(s) in the module.

In your main script, you import the module.

```
Import-Module MyModule
```

In your job, you import the module:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module MyModule

    # Invoke-MyFunction
}
```